# viewWillDisappear firing before UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

If I add an observer for UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification in a UIViewController, it fires after viewWillDisappear.

I have some code in the viewWillDisappear that needs to take a different action based on weather or not the application has been terminated or simply unloaded.

Can anyone suggest what could be done in this situation ?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

A crude hack, but you could add a boolean ivar which you set in `applicationWillTerminate` and then check it in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: But the viewWillDisappear gets called BEFORE applicationWillTerminate... so the order of operation is all wrong.

Comment: Oh darn. Is it possible to do the reverse: have it set normally, and anytime you willingly unload the view unset it before doing so? It's even less elegant than before but I don't know of anything in the API for this, someone must though. Could you explain why you have to do something different?